# OO way to pass a function to a class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am using a legacy C library for networking.  It allows me to create a socket server for example.  I have to pass a function pointer to the library to handle the protocol - e.g. handles things like structure of messages, header lengths, etc.

In a C program you would simply pass a pointer to a function, e.g. `get_protocol`.  But what is the OO way to do this.

I have a wrapper class, lets call it `socket_server`.  I want the capability to pass in at runtime the requisite function pointer for different protocols.

How do I do that?  Is this something the strategy pattern addresses?

EDIT

I like the idea of std::function but we are stuck on VS2008 for the time being so C++11 is not yet open to me.

Comment: Is the function you want to pass a member function of `socket_server`? Can you show some code that demonstrates what you'd like to do?

Comment: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) ?!

Comment: Do you particularly want an OO way? Personally, I'd tend to use generic callable types like `std::function` instead.

Comment: `std::function` means you can use _any_ callable. Which is neat. Esp. with C++11 lambdas and things.

Comment: a functor? a few more to go

Comment: Does the signature of the callback allow for a `void*` generic data?

Comment: To all the people who suggested functors, how is that a solution for a legacy C library?

Comment: If it not possible to use `std::function`, use `boost::function` from Boost. It is essentially the same interface and also works with C++03 (`std::function` from C++11 is a proposal from boost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `std::function`

```
class Test
{
    std::function<void()> func;
public:
    Test(const std::function<void()> &func) : func(func) {}

    void do_something()
    {
        func();
    }
};

void my_func()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test test(my_func);
    test.do_something();
}
```

### Template based

```
template <typename Func>
class Test
{
    Func *func;
public:
    Test(const Func &func) : func(func) {}

    void do_something()
    {
        func();
    }
};

void my_func()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test<void()> test(my_func);
//  Test<decltype(my_func)> test(my_func); // This is even better
    test.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Great, now address the "Legacy C library" part

Comment: Most legacy C libraries use both a pointer to function and pointer to arbitrary void data. `static void function_for_broken_c_api(void* p) noexcept { (*reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()*>(p))(); }` does the thing if you pass a pointer to a std::function. Note that you need to handle the broken exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters suggest you should use the C++11 new feature `std::function`.

Personnally, in C++03 I was already fond of functors. The whole `<algorithm>` header is pro-functors, (and of course now C++11 `std::function`)

A functor is an object which overrides the `operator()`, on which you can call `()` to execute such function.

You can see the `operator()` as a "perform()" function, like a simplified mono-strategy.

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int param_a, const string& param_b)
    {
          // perform what you want
    }
    int my_member;
}

Functor f;
f(0,"go_std_function")
```

But unless you have good reasons, go for `std::function`. It is a generalisation of hand-made functors, and also classic functions: anything that's callable :-).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly. This is what you need to do:

In your Header file, create a function that you want to pass as static. For example:

```
static void* ThreadWorker(void* worker);
```

In your Source file, you would call it like this:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, ThreadWorker, (void *) worker);
```

The function has to be static, since the compiler doesn't know which instance is calling it. But I'm sure someone can explain it better.

Comment: OP wants to have a C++ solution. Loosely typed function pointers aren’t particularly C++-y.

Answer (score 0):

The "OO C" way of doing this would be to also pass through a `void *` value to allow some context to be passed to the callback function. The actual value passed would be a pointer to some kind of `struct` that the callback function would understand (after casting back to the real type). This is not type-safe, but it works really well in practice, and that `struct` can easily hold the pointer to a C++ object, allowing closing of the thunk into a sane API.

If there is no such pointer, you are effectively restricted to calling only static methods as your callbacks (or placing the object references in global variables, which is nasty indeed!) Of course, at that point it is no longer really an OO C interface either, but rather something nasty, and it becomes sane to consider a rewrite or switching to building on top of something else.